# Nice way of doing dual column validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3 for this one.  I've got a collections model, a user model and an intermediate subscription model.  This way a user can subscribe to multiple collections, with a particular role.  However, I don't want a user to be able to subscribe to the same collection twice.

So in my Subscription model I've got something like:

```
validate :subscription_duplicates

def subscription_duplicates
  self.errors.add_to_base "This user is already subscribed" if Subscription.where(:user_id => self.user.id, :collection_id => self.collection.id)
end
```

However this seems ugly.  Also, it breaks when I want to do something like the following in my collection controller:

```
def create
  @collection = Collection.new(params[:collection])
  @collection.subscriptions.build(:user => current_user, :role => Subscription::ROLES['owner'])
  @collection.save
  respond_with(@collection)
end
```

When I do the build the subscription does not have an id so I get a "Called id for nil" error.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use validates_uniqueness_of

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :collection_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your create action should always test if the object was saved, and if not then handle that (usually by re-rendering the new/edit page and showing the errors to the user).

A standard sort of create action would look like this (for a @post in this case):

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @created = @post.save
  respond_to do |format|
    if @created
      flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => :new } #or edit or wherever you got here from
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Shingara's approach to avoiding duplicates should work fine for you.